# A bug in axvline of matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

According to the documentation page:
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html
the way to use the axvline is like

```
axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=1)
```

However, this does not work in my computer.  Nothing is drawn.  Rather, simply

```
axvline(x=0)
```

without setting the ymin and ymax works.

I am not sure whether this is a bug.  Or maybe I missed something subtle?

```
matplotlib.__version__
'0.99.1.1'

uname -a
Linux pc20172 2.6.32-41-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 6 18:00:34 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit: a minimum code to reproduce the problem.

```
from pylab import *
ion()
plot([1,2])
axvline(x=0.5, ymin=1, ymax=2) # No vertical line is drawn.

clf() # Clear the figure to redo the plot.
plot([1,2])
axvline(x=0.5) # Now the desired vertical line is drawn.
```

Comment: Are you sure nothing is drawn?  If this is the only line on the plot, try `axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=1, linewidth=100)` to make it bigger.

Comment: @DSM I don't think there is any thing wrong with the linewidth.  I added a few lines of code that you may test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation in `help(axvline)`:

> Draw a vertical line at *x* from *ymin* to *ymax*.  With the default
>   values of *ymin* = 0 and *ymax* = 1, this line will always span the
>   vertical extent of the axes, regardless of the ylim settings, even if
>   you change them, eg. with the :meth:`set_ylim` command.  **That is,
>   the vertical extent is in axes coords: 0=bottom, 0.5=middle, 1.0=top
>   but the *x* location is in data coordinates.**

So

```
axvline(x=0.5, ymin=1, ymax=2) # No vertical line is drawn.
```

is drawing a line just off the plot area.  If you make the linewidth bigger, you can see this:

[image: pic showing just-out-of-bounds effect]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I also just found this out seconds ago.  It is a bit misleading that x and y are using different coordinate systems.  BTW, your trick of using a very large linewidth is very useful!  I didn't know that increasing the width can also increase the length of a line.

Comment: @user789977: it doesn't increase the length of the line itself, but there's actually a little cap on the end that it's easy not to notice unless it's really big.  See my answer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297220/matplotlib-linewidth-is-added-to-the-length-of-a-line/10297860#10297860).  I should admit though that this only happened to work here by fluke: I originally thought that it was just that the line was hugging a plot edge in one of the cases and it was hard to see.

Answer (score 3):

OK.  Now I realize that the ymin and ymax are not in data coordinate, but rather in the "normalized" coordinate.  So, 0 means bottom of the plot, while 1 means the top.