# Matplotlib: How to prevent transparent color overlay when curve overlaps?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, alpha, alpha-transparency

For example we plot a line with transparent color here

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = 2*a
plt.plot(a, b, 'blue', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

but wenn I plot the same line multiple times,  that overlaps with itself, so that the more it overlaps with itself, the darker it becomes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = 2*a
for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(a, b, 'blue', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

so How can I prevent the color-overlaps?

Thank you all in advance!

**Update: Why I need this?**

I am doing a Tolerance-Analysis. That means, the parameter change themselfs within a samll range and I will plot the curve for each change. Then I can find the worst case.

[image]

If I pick a solid but lighter color. It will looks like:

[image]

As you can see, with untransparent color I can not observe the node, which is covered by other line.

**Update 2:**

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what a transparent line is supposed to do... If you don't like it, pick a solid but lighter color.

Comment: I agree 100% with @NilsWerner. I even consider his comment The Right Answer. I mean _why would someone even consider this undesireable_?

Comment: @heltonbiker I have updated, why I need it.

Comment: @NilsWerner I have updated, why I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single line does not overlay itself. Hence you can concatenate the multiple plots into a single one.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = 2*a

A = np.tile(np.append(a,[np.nan]),3)
B = np.tile(np.append(b,[np.nan]),3)

plt.plot(A, B, 'blue', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is essentially the inverse of this question [How can I draw transparent lines where the color becomes stronger when they overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798232/how-can-i-draw-transparent-lines-where-the-color-becomes-stronger-when-they-over), where this effect was undesired.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it works only for straight line. For Curve the start-point and the end point will be connected with a straight line. I have updated the question

Comment: I updated the answer. However given the updated question, I have problems understanding the issue. You seem to be using two lines per line, one broad transparent one and one narrow, opaque one. Why not simply put the transparent ones in the background?

Comment: Thank  you o lot  for your nice solution. The broad transparent line is not single line. It is a Area, which contains many transparent lines. The narrow opaque line is the curve with ideal value. and the transparent curves rmean parameter with error.

Comment: Anyways, why not simply plot the "area" behind the ideal value?

Comment: The area is constituted by many cuves. How to simply plot the area?  My english is bad, please see the updated figure

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand the issue. Well in that case, the proposed answer here is probably the better choice indeed.

Comment: thanks for your help, another solution is. Find the min and max y-value in each x-value. Then connect all max or min value with line.  By this way the area can be outlined. (Envelope?) But I don't know how to implement.

Comment: If all data of all curves have the same x coordinate, you can concatenate them, find the min and max along the concatenating dimension and use `fill_between` to plot the area.

Comment: very nice! you help me again. I will try it soon