# What is the length of the line cap in data units?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting a line using `matplotlib`, I used `solid_capstyle="round"`. I see that the line extended beyond the assigned length. That is fine for what I want to do. But could I possibly know by how much the line is extended?

Essentially I would like to know the length of the cap.

Demo code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ax=plt.subplot()
ax.plot([0, 100], [15, 15], linewidth=50, linestyle="-", c="red",
         solid_capstyle="round")
ax.axvline(x=100, c="black")
ax.set_xlim(0, 125)
ax.set_ylim(0, 30)
```

[image]

In this example I want to know the length of the cap in terms of the data units. Visually it looks like 9 units (i.e. line extends upto x=109), but I would like to calculate that computationally.

Comment: Yes, as pointed out by one of the answer below, it is mentioned in the matplotlib's doc that `radius = linewidth * 0.5`. But issue is that I need to get the length of the cap in data units. How do I transform the radius to data units? i.e 50 * 0.5 points to ~9 x units.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I noticed that the length measurements change when I change the axis limit, but the change is very minute. So overall I think the way you did it is the best solution, as of now.

Comment: Well, it is the expected behavior. Every time the axis limits change, the line thickness and radius will stay the same in pixels (and in points), but will be different in axes coordinates.  That's just the way axes coordinates work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [radius of the circle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_enums_api.html#matplotlib._enums.CapStyle) is half the width of the line. The [linewidth](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linewidth) uses "points" as unit (using [72 points in an inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)); "points" are also the unit of font size, e.g. a 12 point font size). Note that the units are different in the x and in the y direction and depend on factors such as figure size, xlims and subplot padding.

You can use the [data transform](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) to calculate the radius from points to dots to distance on the x-axis:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot()
linewidth = 50
ax.plot([0, 100], [15, 15], linewidth=linewidth, linestyle="-", c="red",
        solid_capstyle="round")
ax.axvline(x=100, c="black")
ax.set_xlim(0, 125)
ax.set_ylim(0, 30)
radius = linewidth / 2

ppd = 72. / ax.figure.dpi  # points per dot
trans = ax.transData.inverted().transform
x_radius = ((trans((radius / ppd, 0)) - trans((0, 0))))[0]
y_radius = ((trans((0, radius / ppd)) - trans((0, 0))))[1]
print("The radius in the x-direction is", x_radius)
print("The radius in the y-direction is", y_radius)
ax.axvline(x=100 + x_radius, c="black", ls='--')
ax.axhline(y=15 + y_radius, c="black", ls='--')
plt.show()
```

```
The radius in the x-direction is 8.750560035842293
The radius in the y-direction is 2.818362193362194
```

[image: showing cap-radius in data coordinates]

Comment: This is a fantastic looking answer imo. One suggestion is that you can calculate the x and y radii in one call: `x_radius, y_radius = trans((radius / ppd, radius / ppd)) - trans((0, 0))`

Comment: Indeed. I preferred to write the separate calculation, as usually one is only interested in one of the two directions. (I wrote the calculation before I added the idea to show the distances as lines, instead of just a printed value.)

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, definitely works. For some reason, I get incorrect radii/lengths (0.07 and 0.11) when I remove 3 lines `ax.axvline(x=100, c="black");ax.set_xlim(0, 125);ax.set_ylim(0, 30)`. I am not sure why would this happen.